# Why are <link rel> tags from the header showing up on my Wordpress site?

Tags: headers, wp-api, text, shortlink, rel-canonical

I am testing my new WP site. I wanted to see how it worked using a text-only browser, so I fired up "links" from my shell to visit the site. At the top of the page before my navigation menu, the following links were visible:

```
<link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.citizensonline.org.uk/" /> (Yoast)
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='https://www.citizensonline.org.uk/wp-json/' />
<link rel='shortlink' href='https://wp.me/P9c2Zs-1l' />
```

(*Only the words profile, canonical, https://api.w.org/ and shortlink are actually visible, but they are hyperlinked*).

These lines are from the `<head>` section of the source code, so why are they showing up on the page - surely the page should only render content from within the `<body>`, and these header links should be inaccessible to the browser UI? This seems like a bug to me. And presumably one from Wordpress, as this is the only engine that is generating the HTML content.

Maybe this is a bug with the "links" browser rather than a Wordpress bug but I can't find any other reference to this anywhere online. The links are not visible when using a standard browser like Chrome etc.

Other kinds of tag from the head section are not rendered, e.g.:

```
 - <link href
 - <link rel="pingback"
 - <link rel="alternate"
 - <link rel='stylesheet'
 - <link rel='dns-prefetch'
 - <link rel="icon"
 - <link rel="EditURI"
 - <link rel="wlwmanifest"
 - <meta
 - <script
```

... none of these kinds of tag is visible so why would the other 4 be?

I hope somebody can shed some light on this for me. Thank you!

Comment: Something is adding broken HTML to your head somewhere, causing this to happen. Look at the raw HTML of the page (by going to Resources/Sources tab of the inspector) and see if there's any broken tags or similar. Or post the full contents of `<head>` so people here could see.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I can't see any obvious problems, though there is a lot of stuff in the head. I've pasted it here (though it's obv available through view:source anyway) https://pastebin.com/6RCrh8pk

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your missing the / before the close on profile
Try  this

```
<link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah - well spotted! Hard to believe I had missed that myself. Anyway, I've fixed it but the links are still showing when viewed in a text-only browser.